# Getting too many file descriptor open, in java application while performing file operation

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu

By using `files.list()` API of `java.nio.file.Files` I am getting open FD of Directory when I open the directory for finding files.
So can anybody help why this API causing such issue?

Becasue after method block end instance of `Object[]` paths, must be clear by garbage collector and File descriptor should be close automatically.

My application is running on Ubuntu.

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
Object[] paths=Files.list(dir.path)
         .filter(p -> p.getFileName().toString().contains(".txt")).toArray();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Streams are closeable objects, and the [api documentation of Files.list()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#list-java.nio.file.Path-) states:

> the try-with-resources construct should be used to ensure that the stream's close method is invoked after the stream operations are completed.

So, you should do:

```java
final Path[] paths;
try (Stream<Path> dirList = Files.list(dir.path)) {
    paths = dirList.filter(...).toArray(size -> new Path[size]);
}
```

In general, I advise you to check any object obtained from a path, and if AutoCloseable, encapsulate it with try-with-resource. Without it, Java does not know when to close the related system resource.

If you've got the `too many files opened` error at the line of code you pasted, it might be another file operation in your program that is not closed properly either. In this case, you can use IDE inspection tools or other tools like spotBugs, sonar, etc. to find the problematic statements.

**EDIT**:
`Files.list` returns a *lazily* filled list. It means java will maintain connection to operating system, and queries directory content as user browse it. The stream should be closed, so the OS resource is released *as soon as* you've ended iteration upon it.

Java provides AutoCloseable API to handle external resource release, because GC cannot be trusted for this operation:

- GC release java managed memory, **not** external resources
- Anyway, there **no guarantee** about GC cleaning timing. It could happen next second or next minute. It's not reliable for resources that need to be handled in a timely manner.

*Example*: If external resource cleaning were delegated to GC, there would be serious problems when JVM crashes suddenly: all resources waiting for garbage collection wouldn't be properly released.
With an explicit construct, you're assured that all opened resources have been closed as soon as possible, and it reduce number of possibly corrupted ones in case of a crash.

Comment: Yes,try-with-resource worked fine for me.But I not understand why this problem come.Path object will return files name as arraylist which was present in Directory

Comment: I tested , only above line causing issue in my Application.